# scala use case match output depending on type

Tags: scala

How to modify `Foobar` process method so I can use case match output and call `run(data)` once and not three times? Is it possible to set some common type for `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` and if case match output is specific type then call run(data) else if unknown mode then raise exception?

This is my code:

```
object Foobar {
    def process(someConfig: String, someVar: String, data: Seq[String]) = {
        someConfig match {
            case "a" => new ClassA(someVar).run(data)
            case "b" => new ClassB(someVar).run(data)
            case "c" => new ClassC(someVar).run(data)
            case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown mode")

class ClassA(someVar: String) {
    def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
        // do some processing 1 with data & someVar
        ...
    }

class ClassB(someVar: String) {
    def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
        // do some processing 2 with data & someVar
        ...
    }

class ClassC(someVar: String) {
    def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
        // do some processing 3 with data & someVar
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do, is define a trait with `def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit` method, and then extend if from the other classes. Something like:

```scala
trait Letter {
  def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit
}

class ClassA(someVar: String) extends Letter {
  override def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
    println(data)
  }
}

class ClassB(someVar: String) extends Letter {
  override def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
    println(data)
  }
}

class ClassC(someVar: String) extends Letter {
  override def run(data: Seq[String]) = {
    println(data)
  }
}

object Foobar {
  def process(someConfig: String, someVar: String, data: Seq[String]) = {
    val letter = someConfig match {
      case "a" => new ClassA(someVar)
      case "b" => new ClassB(someVar)
      case "c" => new ClassC(someVar)
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown mode")
    }

    letter.run(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit mappers for that

```
sealed trait Letter { def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit }
case class A(someVar: String) extends Letter { override def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit = println("A") }
case class B(someVar: String) extends Letter { override def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit = println("B") }
case class C(someVar: String) extends Letter { override def run(data: Seq[String]): Unit =  println("C") }

// This can be in mappers object
implicit class ClassesMapper(someConfig: String) {
    def toClass(someVar: String): Letter = {
      someConfig match {
        case "a" => A(someVar)
        case "b" => B(someVar)
        case "c" => C(someVar)
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("<exception>")
      }
    }
}


object Foobar {
    def process(someConfig: String, someVar: String, data: Seq[String]) = {
      someConfig.toClass(someVar).run(data)
    }
}

Foobar.process("a", "someVar", Nil)
```

Output: `A`